# Python all Function with Multiple Iterables

Tags: python

I have a list of files and want to set a flag if a given file name doesn't exist in the list. So I have:

```
if all('FileName' not in f for f in files):
    # set flag
```

I want to expand this check to look for multiple file names, so I created a list of file names:

```
file_names = ['FileName', 'FileName2']
```

In psuedo code, I'm looking for:

```
if all(#all file names in files_names# not in f for f in files):
    # set flag
```

Can I still use the built-in all function somehow to acheive this in one line? Or do I need to break it apart into multiple statements?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand this correctly... One way would be to convert both into sets:

```
files = set(files)
file_names = set(file_names)

if not file_names <= files:
    # set flag
```

Note that `<=` is a subset operator (shortcut for `.issubset`).

**EDIT** If you want to check whether ALL files are not in `files` then you can use the intersection operator `&` (or `.intersection` method) to check whether there are common elements in both sets:

```
if not file_names & files:
    # set flag
```

If you want to keep list structure then you can use temporary convertions:

```
if not set(file_names) & set(files):
    # set flag
# file_names is still a list
```

That solution is not only elegant but also efficient. Read more about sets here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

**EDIT 2** In case when you want to check whether names from `file_names` are *contained* (unlike my solution where I only check for strict equality between names) in names from `files` then you can use this:

```
if all(all(name not in fn for fn in files) for name in file_names):
    # set flag
```

Quite similar to the pseudocode you've written. It shows how beautiful Python is. :D Using sets doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: Shouldn't there be code that changes the values back to list? Maybe just `if not set(file_names).issubset(set(files)):` to avoid bugs due to type issues later

Comment: Thanks for your response! I only want to set the flag if ALL items in file_names are not in files. I feel like your approach will set the flag if ANY item in file_names is not in files. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3443674 Yes, that's correct. In that case try the intersection: `if not file_name & files:`

Comment: @Calpratt That depends. If he does not need the order of files then he can use sets. But generally I agree.

Comment: I'm just realizing this problem is more complicated than I thought. `file_names` may not be the full string in `files`. So if I imagine one iteration of the intersection operation, I think of `file_names[x] == files[y]` but I really need `file_names[x] in files[y]` Any ideas?

Comment: There's that nested all I couldn't figure out! Thanks again, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually avoid casting them separately as sets, if you want to continue to operate on them as lists, for example:

```
if not set(file_names).issubset(files):
    # set flag

type(file_names)
```

would still return:

```
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your first use of `all()` was unnecessary as it looks like all you need is:

```
if 'FileName' not in files:
#set flag
```

The new question you pose however can benefit from `all()` or depending on what you want to achieve (the output of `all()` can be a little deceiving) you may also use `any()` since according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) `all()` actually

> Return[s] True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the
>   iterable is empty)

Which means that if you have a 'filename' and you are checking the list of `files` that the following scenarios exist

```
# all file names present in files
file_names = ['file','file1','file2']
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
not all(f in files for f in file_names) #False
```

and

```
# no file names to be compared against
file_names = []
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
not all(f in files for f in file_names) # True
```

and

```
# some file names not present in files
file_names = ['file','foo','bar','baz']
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
not all(f in files for f in file_names) # True
```

You'll notice that last two are the same, and in these ambiguous cases I prefer to use `any()` which as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) will

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

such that

```
# all file names present in files
file_names = ['file','file1','file2']
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
any(f not in files for f in file_names) # False
```

and

```
# no file names to be compared against
file_names = []
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
any(f not in files for f in file_names) # False
```

and

```
# some file names not present in files
file_names = ['file','foo','bar','baz']
files # with files ['file','file1','file2','filen']
any(f not in files for f in file_names) # True
```

Which means that you don't have to perform any additional logic to determine whether `files` is empty or not. This is an edge case, however, and it seems that you have control over what `files` contains so either `any()` or `all()` should suffice.

In the extended case where you want to check to see if your `file_name` is contained within the name of a file in your list (whew that was fun to write) then as #freakish stated you can nest `any()` or `all()` statements

```
all(all(name not in fn for fn in files) for name in file_names):
# set flag
```

While this works for your case I think a more useful and sexier halfway [DeMorgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) inverted version is

```
all(not any(name in file for file in files) for name in file_names)
```

Why is it more useful? Because simply taking out the `not` now allows another useful question: Do any of the files for which I'm looking exist?